# R, is it possible to read a CSV file from the end row the beginning row?

Tags: r, csv

When I read in a CSV file to draw a plot, is it possible to read the CSV data in the order from bottom to up?

```
Position, value
1,    90
2,    88
3,    34
4,    45
5,    45
6,    89
7,    53
......
```

The order I want the CSV to be read in:

```
......
7,    53
6,    89
5,    45
4,    45
3,    34
2,    88
1,    90
```

My real data sheet would have thousands rows.

Comment: The physical order of the rows in a data.frame object is largely irrelevant for almost all operations in R. What are you trying to do that would require you to have the data in a particular order?

Comment: I am doing something about the sequencing, sample picture: http://www.cureffi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/paired-end1.jpg. for the sequence from right to left, the order of data in csv file is from left to right (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,...), but when the data is represented in the plot, the order should be from the right to left (...,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)

Comment: I am trying to write a script to convert the csv file in the reverse order, but curious to know if there is a r function to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you have really specific reasons to really read from the bottom, you can always sort after reading it the usual way... e.g.

```
my.data <- read.csv(...)
my.data <- my.data[nrow(my.data):1,]
```